# TS1128 Error -- Angular 4.4.6 Prod Build Failure

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out if I have an Angular bug here or if it is perhaps some sort of config issue. Angular 4.4.6 w/CLI and @ngtools/webpack is what I'm using
My scenario to reproduce is this:

1) I am developing locally and am able to build and deploy with, say, and extra curly brace or comma in a ts file *sometimes* The sometimes part is unfortunately not very quantifiable, I know, but I'm just being honest

2) I am able to make changes and Angular's CLI reload serves up changes w/out a problem

3) I through it in my pipeline and the build fails, with the following message:

[image: build stacktrace]

So, in short, it builds, deploys and works just find locally, although there is some slight syntax error. But the build fails when deploying prod.

Something like this can be easy to miss (not counting a linter or hinter, b/c Visual Studio 2017 hinter is not picking this up at compile time... at least not right away)
Just wondering if anyone has ran into this before I create a bug w/Angular

**** EDIT *******

Excerpt from package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"lint": "tslint --project . --force",
"test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js",
"start": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js",
"postinstall": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js",
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js -p --env=prod && webpack -p --env=prod"
```

},

Excerpt from webpack.config.js:

```
 module.exports = (env) => {
// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
const sharedConfig = {
    stats: { modules: false },
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: 'dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular-router-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'] : '@ngtools/webpack'
            },
            { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader?minimize=false' },
            { test: /\.css$/, use: ['to-string-loader', isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize'] },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' }

        ]
    },
    plugins: [new CheckerPlugin()]
};
```

Comment: Is there a line number or anything specific? Regarding #1, do you mean adding an erroneous character that should make it fail sometimes does/does not?  99% of the time it's not a bug with the package. Can you re-create this as minimally as possible and share?

Comment: Phix thanks for the quick reply! Yes, it says a line number above (just trying not to show our project specific proj info) that is how I found and fixed it quickly. The thing is this is like the 3rd time in the last month that everything has worked fine locally, but when deploying to prod we get one of these funny errors. Easy to fix but hard to justify

Comment: I believe the prod builds with stricter rules, I've run into similar issues but it's just making sure everything is linted strictly. Run with `ng serve -prod` to see if it occurs there as well. Edit: for future reference it's difficult for a stranger to debug without code. If you're worried about sensitive info replace it with foo bars so we have at least an idea.

Comment: @Phix I just added a bit more info..still a bit new at this

Comment: Is the error triggered on your webpack config?  Based on your original question something in the actual Angular code is messing up.

Comment: @Phix no nothing new just wanted to add that setup..